# Bootstrap 3 Tooltip automatically change placement from right to left

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I can't make a Bootstrap 3 Tooltip to automatically change placement from right to left when getting closer to parent boundary:

```
$('.pic').on('mouseover', '.pin', function(e) {
  $(this).attr('title', 'zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz');
  $(this).tooltip({
    'placement': 'auto right',
    'boundary': $(this)
  });
  $(this).tooltip('show');
});

$('.pic').on('mouseout', '.pin', function(e) {
  $(this).tooltip('dispose');
});
```

See Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0egk47n9/20/

Comment: you have included bootstrap 4 in fiddle. please change!!

Comment: Oops, sorry. Changed it. But now it's even worse. I want it to show the tooltip on the right for the .left pin and on the left for the .right pin

Comment: Made a mistake, I've update the Fiddle. Now both tooltips show on the right, I want the one going outside of the pic boundary to change its position.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution: https://codepen.io/creativedev/pen/VdQgNW

```
$('.pic').on('mouseover', '.pin', function(e) {
    $(this).attr('title', 'zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz');
    $(this).tooltip({
        placement: function(tip, element) {
            var position = $(element).position();
            var cls = $(element).attr('class').split(/\s+/);
            if (cls[1].indexOf('right') > -1) {
                var d = "left";
            } else {
                var d = "right";
            }
            return d;
        },
    });
    $(this).tooltip('show');
});
```

Comment: The right/left class was not the input for the tooltip. The classes are named so for simplicity. They can be named whatever. But the tooltip shoud change position if it goes out of boundary regardless of the class name.

Comment: you can add any specific class in the element and use that!!

Comment: auto is not managing left and right only, it is for auto placement so it may be in bottom, left, top or right

Comment: according to the docs it is, it's supposed to change placement automatically depending on the boundary

Comment: yeah but it may be bottom or top also,not only left or right

Comment: top/bottom is not important for me, but left/right is

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm very late to this party, but I stumbled on this while looking for something else. The problem is that `boundary` isn't an option. What you want is `viewport`. So instead of `'boundary': $(this)`, set it to `'viewport': '.pic'`.

See docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#tooltips